# recyclerview offscreen edittext value is null

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview with an edit text inside it the user enter numbers inside edit text and when he click save button a for loop iterate over all the recyclerview edit text and save data to Firebase my problem is that if there is list of data more than the screen size all the values that are off-screen are ignored and their values are saved as empty value only the items displayed on-screen are saved her is my code

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchases_list_activity, container, false);
    mItem = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new PurchasesAdapter(getContext(), mItem, this);
    re = view.findViewById(R.id.itemsPListView);
    re.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    re.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    assert user != null;
    userid = user.getUid();
    usersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userid);
    usersDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    usersDatabase.child("p").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                p = (dataSnapshot.child("p").getValue()).toString();
                purchasesDatabase = usersDatabase.child("purchases").child("p").child(p).child("Cigarette");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    itemsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userid).child("items").child("Cigarette");
    itemsDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    itemsDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mItem.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot teacherSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ItemsAdapter upload = teacherSnapshot.getValue(ItemsAdapter.class);
                upload.setKey(teacherSnapshot.getKey());
                mItem.add(upload);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    fabItem = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_purchases_add_item);
    fabItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addItem();

        }
    });


    fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_purchases);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mItem.size(); i++) {
                final ItemsAdapter mylist = mItem.get(i);
              -------------------------------------
              - View childView = re.getChildAt(i);-
              ------------------------------------- 
                i think my problem is her inside the dash box


                final EditText Qty = childView.findViewById(R.id.itemNewPcs);
                final String qty = Qty.getText().toString();

                    final Map<String, Object> note = new HashMap<>();
                    note.put(KEY_ITEMID, mylist.getItemID());
                    note.put(KEY_ITEMSQTY, qty);
                    note.put(KEY_ITEMNAME, mylist.getItemName());
                    usersDatabase.child("inventory").child("p").child(p).child("Cigarette")
                            .child(mylist.getItemID()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                                dataSnapshot.getRef().updateChildren(note);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a RecyclerView, the off-screen views are recycled (hence the name of the widget) to a pool of views and reused later when new items scroll into view.  You should not use them after they have been removed from view, as you don't know what item of data they're attached to any more.

If you need to retain an entire set of views even after they've been scrolled away from view, don't use a RecyclerView.  Just assemble the entire set of views into a single ScrollView, so that they are always in memory as the view is scrolled.

Comment: but i need to use recyclerview to fetch Firebase data inside it and then save the new data entered to Firebase her is a screenshot http://prntscr.com/ofy4g8 the left column is the item name which is taken from firebase(with a recyclerview adapter to bind the data )and the right column is the quantity that the user should enter and when fab button is clicked i iterate through the data entered

Comment: You have no obligation to use a RecyclerView with a Firebase query.

Comment: is there another way to not recycler the view you could suggest may solve the problem

Comment: i didnt use firebase query with recyclerview btw i dont have problem with firebase my problem is when i iterate throw the recyclerview and get the entered data from it